# I'm trying to perform editing operations in cakephp 2,i'm getting Missing argument 1 for UsersController::edit() and Undefined variable: id

Tags: cakephp

this is my UsersController file,below its given edit action,without passing id it is working fine,but in next form too but id is becoming visible.

```
public function edit($id){
$data=$this->User->findbyId($id);
if($this->request->is(array('post','put'))){
    $this->User->id=$id;                //id is passed from one form to another
    if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
    $this->session->setFlash('Edited successfully');
    $this->redirect('index');
    $this->request->data=$data;
}
    }
}


 this is my edit.ctp flie

<html>
<body>
<h1>Edit a new user </h1>
<?php 
    echo $this->form->create('User');
    //echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->end('save');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is the data not saved, or are duplicate entries created?

Comment: Are you passing an `id` parameter in the URL? If not in won't work as expected. Passing `id` via the form (`echo $this->Form->input('id');`) is not the same as passing it via the URL. The form value will not be passed as `$id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting that missing arguments error when the URL looks like ..../users/edit instead of ..../users/edit/2? In that case, change this

```
   public function edit($id) 

           to 

   public function edit($id = null)
```

Also, if no id is passed in the URL, it should give us an error message since we are not sure which user we need to edit.

Try this,

```
           if(!$id){

               $this->Session->setFlash("User not found!");

               $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
           }

           $data   =   $this->User->findbyId($id);

           if(empty($data)){

               $this->Session->setFlash("User not found!");

               $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
           }
```

Peace! xD

Comment: yeah after adding  edit (!$id=null) it's working fine.Thanks :)